# Deploy react build with docker on apache or aws

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apache, amazon-web-services, docker

I am new to docker and react. I want to know how to deploy a production build on AWS.
Steps which I already tried are below:

1. Create a dockerfile.
2. Built and ran it on the server.
3. `npm run` and `npm run build` are working inside the container.
4. Expose the build folder via volume.

**Now my question is: How can I deploy it on AWS with Apache-HTTP-Server and expose the service on port 80?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are already close. You just need to install an Apache Webserver into the docker container.

BUT you dont need to do it yourself. You can just start your dockerfile with `FROM httpd:latest` to use the [official apache container](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/) as a base.

My reccomendation would be to use two docker containers with one shared volume. The first container builds your app from source and exits after work is done. The second container hosts apache with the build directory mounted to its htdocs directory. That way you could use the [official apache container](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/) without modifications and you already created build-container.

The third option would be to use node instead of apache for hosting, then theres the [nodejs container](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/) available to use as a base, and an instruction manual on how to use it [here](https://dzone.com/articles/running-a-react-app-in-a-docker-container).

Also you might be interested in shakyShane's [awesome post](https://medium.com/@shakyShane/lets-talk-about-docker-artifacts-27454560384f) where he describes how to solve this issue using a single dockerfile

EDIT: I am using this [Dockerfile](https://gist.github.com/manzari/ee47a98e1a30edf2aa6d5b066f34a959) now. However you should specify ports in a docker-compose file or so.

Comment: thank you so much  Marco. its really helpful. I just need 1 more confirmation . after FROM httpd:latest can how  can run build   folder on default port (80)

Comment: you need to get the contents of your `build` directory to the default directory where Apache looks for files to serve. The directory is: `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs`. You can do it by adding `COPY /path/to/build /usr/local/apache2/htdocs` in the docker file or use volume mapping s

Comment: you means get the copy of my build to outside the container and i can place it on the server root folder . right ?

Comment: No you need the contents of your `build` directory inside your container in apaches `htdocs` folder. you can copy from outside to the inside of your container using `COPY` in the docker file. or you can map an outside directory to the `htdocs` direcoty inside the container. you can read more on docker volumes [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)